# Are there more reliable formulas for finding global minima?

Tags: calculus, optimization, machine-learning

I was playing around with Desmos today and came up with this formula for finding global minima:

[image]

It works by descending until it finds a negative value. The same method could work with multiple variables using nested products. Would that be a computationally feasible method to use in machine learning?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It’s not clear what algorithm you’re describing. A more clear explanation would be helpful.

Comment: The most often used optimization algorithm in machine learning is gradient descent which has the flaw of often getting caught in local minimas. This method always detects global minima but I'm not sure if it can work on a scale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @littleO pointed out, it is really not clear what your method/algorithm is. Trying to interpret your image, my guess is that you are doing the following:

1. Start with $n=0$ and $g_0(x) = f(x)$
2. Increase $n$ by 1 (ie $n \leftarrow n+1$)
3. Let $g_n(x) = g_{n-1}(x)(f(x)-n)$
4. Check if $g_n(x) < 0$ has solutions
5. If so, the solution set is a union of neighbourhoods of gloabl minimizers, and the global minimum, $m$ satisfies $n-1 \leq m < n$.
6. Else, go to step 2.

If this is correct, then there are some flaws. First, assuming $g_{n-1}(x)=\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}(f(x)-i) < 0$ has no solutions, then checking if $g_{n}(x)=\prod_{i=1}^{n}(f(x)-i) < 0$ is the same as checking if $f(x)-n < 0$ has solutions (which is in turn equivalent to checking if $f(x) < n$ has solutions).
So if I have interpreted your algorithm correctly it ultimately boils down to linearly checking "is 0 the minimum?$, "is 1 the minimum?", "is 2 the minimum?", etc. But the minimum value of the function need not be a natural number. So you would have to modify it to handle real numbers (including negative reals).

The bigger issue is you need a method for actually finding solutions to $f(x) < n$. Your post gives no indication of how you would do that, essentially ignoring all of the difficulty of optimization.